# property content is set more once

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I give error the property content is set more once.

How I can place stackpanel and listview in one page?

I want to place ddl in stackpanel

```
 <UserControl x:Class="D.O.L.U.U"
                 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,17">
         </StackPanel>

    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" SelectionChanged="Changed">
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp" Handler="Click" />
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                        </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enclose your code in a `<Grid>` when you have multiple elements on your control. And enclose your DDL in the Stackpanel that way:

```
<UserControl x:Class="D.O.L.U.U"
                 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
   <Grid>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,17">
         <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" SelectionChanged="Changed">
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
               <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                  <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp" Handler="Click" />
               </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                  <Grid>
                     <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                  </Grid>
               </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
         </ListView>
      </StackPanel>
   </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The `Grid` is the most basic and probably most used element in WPF, you can add as elements as you want inside.

In Visual Studio, when you create a new `UserControl`, the `Grid` tag is automatically present. You can of course remove it when you know that your control will contain only one element.

I also noticed you were missing the closing tag on UserControl, typo? Anyway, I've added it in my code.